# Maximizing sum of logarithms (Z-channel capacity)

Tags: probability, functions, derivatives, logarithms, information-theory

In the context of information theory, I am trying to maximize the following function (mutual information of the Z-channel's input and output) with respect to $p$ in order to derive Z-channel's capacity:
$$I(X;Y)=\mathit{H}(ap)-\mathit{H}(1-a)p$$
where $\mathit{H}(x)=-xlog_2(x)-(1-x)log_2(1-x)$, $0<x<1$ is known as the binary entropy function.
So the function is:
$$I(X;Y)=-aplog_2(ap)-(1-ap)log_2(1-ap)-\mathit{H}(1-a)p$$
Differentiating with respect to $p$ I get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial I(X;Y)}{\partial p}&=&-alog_2(ap)-ap\frac{1}{pln2}+alog_2(1-ap)-(1-ap)\frac{a}{ln2(ap-1)}-\mathit{H}(1-a)\\
&=&log_2((ap)^{-a}e^{-a}(1-ap)^{-a}e^aa^a(1-a)^{1-a})\\
&=&log_2((ap)^{-a}(1-ap)^{-a}a^a(1-a)^{1-a})
\end{eqnarray*}
Then:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial I(X;Y)}{\partial p}=0&\Rightarrow &log_2((ap)^{-a}(1-ap)^{-a}a^a(1-a)^{1-a})=0\\
&\Rightarrow &(ap)^{-a}(1-ap)^{-a}a^a(1-a)^{1-a}=1\\
\end{eqnarray*}
I can't solve this. Eventually, I am trying to prove that the value of $p$ that maximizes the function is:
$$p=\frac{1}{a(1+2^{\mathit{H}(1-a)/a})}$$
More information on the Z-channel can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-channel_(information_theory)), but I am using different notation regarding the probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to separate the process using the chain rule instead of using the full equation for I:
$$I=H(ap)-H(1-a)p$$
$$\frac{dI}{dp}=\frac{dH(ap)}{d(ap)}\frac{d(ap)}{dp}-H(1-a)=\frac{dH(ap)}{d(ap)}a-H(1-a)$$
Now we need to find $H'$
$$\frac{dH}{dx}=-log_2(x)-x\frac{1}{x  ln2}+log_2(1-x)+(1-x)\frac{1}{(1-x)ln2}=\frac{-ln(x)-1+ln(1-x)+1}{ln2}=log_2(1-x)-log_2(x)$$
Substituting in the previous equation with $x=ap$:
$$\frac{dI}{dp}=a(log_2(1-ap)-log_2(ap))-H(1-a)$$
Setting $dI/dp=0$
$$\frac{H(1-a)}{a}=log_2(1-ap)-log_2(ap)$$
$$2^{\frac{H(1-a)}{a}}=2^{log_2(1-ap)-log_2(ap)}=\frac{2^{log_2(1-ap)}}{2^{log_2(ap)}}=\frac{1-ap}{ap}$$
$$ap2^{\frac{H(1-a)}{a}}+ap=1$$
$$ap(2^{\frac{H(1-a)}{a}}+1)=1$$
$$p=\frac{1}{a(2^{\frac{H(1-a)}{a}}+1)}$$